# EF4 Code First: how to create a transaction and change isolation level

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I am using the EF4 code first for db access. I needed to wrap some changes in a transaction and change the isolation level to repeatable read. It would be a cinch to write this in SQL, but EF is giving me a hard time. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `TransactionScope`:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
       new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepetableRead} ))
{
    // Grab data
    // Process changes
    context.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```